# Format string with no decimals OR 2 decimals

Tags: php

I have a float number. I want to convert it to a string with the following two rules

- If the float has no decimal part then do not create any decimal part
- If the float has a decimal part then convert it to two decimal places

For example

```
499 => "499"
499.5 => "499.50"
499.99 => "499.99"
499.989 => "499.99"
```

How would you do that in php?

Comment: what about `499.0001` ? should it return `499` or `499.00` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `number_format` with [Type Casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) `(string)` in PHP

```
$numbers = array(499,499.5,499.99,499.989);
foreach ( $numbers as $number ) {
    var_dump(__format($number));
}
```

Function used

```
function __format($number) {
    if (is_float($number)) {
        return number_format($number, 2);
    } else {
        return (string) $number;
    }
}
```

Output

```
string '499' (length=3)
string '499.50' (length=6)
string '499.99' (length=6)
string '499.99' (length=6)
```

Comment: It's not remotely the same as asked in the original question.

Comment: @N.B guide me .. what changed ??? Carlos asked 1. If the float has no decimal part then do not create any decimal part , 2. If the float has a decimal part then convert it to two decimal places and he wanted it has a string

Comment: That fails the first test case of "499 => "499""

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick for you:

```
if(round(($var*100),0)%100==0)
{
    echo round($var,0);
}
else
{
    echo round($var,2);
}
```

There might be a much more elegant way of doing it, but this will work in the following way:

If the float multiplied by a 100 and rounded ends in 00 (close enough to round to no decimals) then it is echoed without any decimal places. Otherwise it is rounded to two decimal places - the float should take care of rounding too much so I think there will always be two spots visible.